# Style: Image float right in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, styles

I need to be able to float images to the right or left, in the ckeditor, as in this example:

http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets (see under Enhanced images)

I've downloaded the plugin and I've added the following code to my ckeditor-replace:

```
extraPlugins: 'image2',
          removePlugins: 'loremipsum, texttransform, liveedit',
    image2_alignClasses: [ 'image-left', 'image-center', 'image-right' ],
    image2_captionedClass: 'image-captioned'...
```

Then, in my css-file, I floated the classes to their respective values: left, right (when I choose to float the image to the right, under the source, I see that it is given the class image-right). So far so good, but like I said, the changes need to occur in the ckeditor. The user needs to see how his document will look like.

Where, or what, in the styles, do I need to change the behavior in the ckeditor? I checked the style documentation, but it's still unclear to me how I manipulate the classes (if that's what I need to do).

For instance, this:

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'foo' } } );
```

I figured I'd need to target the class image-right and give it a float, right.

Suggestions?

Comment: Check the [What's New in Widgets in CKEditor 4.4?](http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.4.0/widget-styles.html) demo that shows how to use classes to align captioned image widgets. The documentation is available here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_captionedimage-section-image-alignment-and-classes

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right place. The magic code is this:   contentsCss: [
        CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'contents.css' ),
        // Add CSS for widget styles.
        'assets/widgetStyles.css'
    ], --which I found under the js tab. A bit obscure. You guys did a great job...but certain things could be made clearer. If you give this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation of the Captioned Image feature](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_captionedimage-section-image-alignment-and-classes), you need to define the CSS rules for these classes in your stylesheet. Once this configuration option is set, corresponding style definitions must be supplied to the editor:

- For [classic editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) it can be done by defining additional styles in the stylesheets loaded by the editor. The same styles must be provided on the target page where the content will be loaded.
- For [inline editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) the styles can be defined directly with `<style> ... <style>` or `<link href="..." rel="stylesheet">`, i.e. within the `<head>` section of the page.

As for defining the stylesheets for editor content, use the [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) configuration option, e.g:

```
config.contentsCss = [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/mywidgetstyles.css' ];
```

See the following [showcase](http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.4.0/widget-styles.html) of captioned image styling and alignment done through classes.